# Splitting lists into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df:

```
  name    time
1  a      1 year 2 months
2  b      4 years 1 month
3  c      3 years 1 month
```

I want to end with:

```
  name    years   months
1  a      1       2
2  b      4       1
3  c      3       1
```

I can get as far as:

```
  name    time
1  a      [1, 2]
2  b      [4, 1]
3  c      [3, 1]
```

but I can't figure out how to split the lists into columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                   'time': ['1 year 2 months', '4 years 1 month', '3 years 1 month']})

# Split the time column and take the first and third elements to extract the values.
df[['years', 'months']] = df.time.str.split(expand=True).iloc[:, [0, 2]].astype(int)

>>> df
   name             time  years months
0     a  1 year 2 months      1      2
1     b  4 years 1 month      4      1
2     c  3 years 1 month      3      1
```

You can use `del df['time']` when you're ready to drop that column.

Comment: Absolutely works. Minor issue with my data, by using this I found that there are a few entries where time is "1-11 months" without a year before them. Any thoughts on how to handle that?

Comment: Add this as a preprocessing step: `mask = df.time.str.contains('years')` 
`df.time.loc[~mask] = '0 years ' + df.time.loc[~mask]`

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you very much, I've learnt a ton with this project.

Comment: Just noticed something, this solution doesn't take into account the 1 year vs 2+ years case. Just changed the mask to 'year' instead of 'years' and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to find digits in your time columns and then with [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) you could get your result:

```
In [240]: df.time.str.findall('\d').str.join('_').str.split('_', expand=True)
Out[240]:
   0  1
0  1  2
1  4  1
2  3  1

df[['years', 'months']] = df.time.str.findall('\d').str.join('_').str.split('_', expand=True)

In [245]: df
Out[245]:
  name             time years months
0    a  1 year 2 months     1      2
1    b  4 years 1 month     4      1
2    c  3 years 1 month     3      1
```

It's a bit faster then @Alexander's solution, and I think more general. From **timing**:

```
In [6]: %timeit df.time.str.split(expand=True).iloc[:, [0, 2]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit df.time.str.findall('\d').str.join('_').str.split('_', expand=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop
```